# using mysqldump comment directives

Tags: mysql, directive

I've been using mysql for a very long time, but didn't really look into one of its features - directives inside a dump. I'm currently working on partitioning, so let's take it for an example and let's look at code from http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html:

```
show create table t2\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t2
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE (to_seconds(dt))
(PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN (63426787200) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN (63426816000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p03 VALUES LESS THAN (63426844800) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p04 VALUES LESS THAN (63426873600) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p05 VALUES LESS THAN (63426902400) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p06 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = MyISAM) */
```

The thing I'm interested in is `/*!50500 [...] */`. What is it and how it works? I assume it's kind of a directive for mysql when parsing the dump file. As for a directive, I guess it can be switched on or off. That would be cool - I could have a database dump with tables partitioned and - while switching off 50500 directive - I could load the dump without partitioning (it'd be ignored, I guess). Is that possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's neither a mysqldump feature nor a directive code or name. It's good old [MySQL conditional comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html):

> If you add a version number after the “!” character, the syntax
>   within the comment is executed only if the MySQL version is greater
>   than or equal to the specified version number. The TEMPORARY keyword
>   in the following comment is executed only by servers from MySQL
>   3.23.02 or higher:
>
> ```
> CREATE /*!32302 TEMPORARY */ TABLE t (a INT);
> ```
>
> The comment syntax just described applies to how the mysqld server
>   parses SQL statements. The mysql client program also performs some
>   parsing of statements before sending them to the server. (It does this
>   to determine statement boundaries within a multiple-statement input
>   line.)
>
> Comments in this format, /*!12345 ... */, are not stored on the
>   server. If this format is used to comment stored routines, the
>   comments will not be retained on the server.

Thus `50500` stands for **MySQL 5.5.0 or greater**. It's a way to ensure that dumps can get restored in older servers.